# PHP rounding gives 00 as an answer

Tags: php

I have a simple bit of PHP which is meant to round a floating number to 5 decimal places but I get an odd result which is `00`

This is my code:

```
$sum = (2*pi()) / (rand(5,10)*(0+1)*60*60*1000);
echo $sum.'<br/>';
echo round($sum,5);
```

And this result:

```
2.90888208666E-7
00
```

I am going to assume this is expected behavior for `round()` but am unsure how I can solve the problem so I can get the number to 5 decimal places.

What is the cause of this problem, and how should I solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the number to 5 decimal places. `2.90888208666E-7` is so small (as you can tell by the `E-7` at the end, that in five decimal places, it rounds to 0.

The `E-7` at the end actually has meaning! It's a way to say `2.90888 * pow(10, -7)` or `2.90888 * 0.000001`. See ["Number with E" on Math.StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142588/how-can-i-calculate-the-number-withe) or ["E-Notation" on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation).

So, the number you have is `0.000000290888208666`, (give or take a zero ;)). This number is so small that if you round to 5 decimals it becomes 0.

Additionally, a float is still a float and irrelevant zeroes aren't displayed if you echo a float. 
To show them, you need to format the number to a string, and telling PHP exactly how many decimals you want. You could use [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) for this.

```
$output = round($sum, 5);
echo number_format($output, 5);
```

Comment: _"You have the number to 5 decimal places"_. +1

Comment: Why does it remove the 2? Surely it would be `2.9089`

Comment: the number is so small and it round to zero

Comment: The number is `2.0...` why would that be `0.etc` ?

Comment: As I said in the answer. The number you have is `0.000000290888208666`, (give or take a zero ;)). This number is so small that if you round to 5 decimals it becomes 0. Pay attention to the `E-7` at the end. It actually has meaning! It's a way to say `2.90888 * pow(10, -7)` or `2.90888 * 0.000001`. See ["Number with E" on Math.StackExchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142588/how-can-i-calculate-the-number-withe).

Comment: Ah, i understand now, is there any way I can get the true number to some decimal places, as I need to pass back to javascript with JSON. Otherwise i'm just passing 0 all the time.

Comment: @Dave: You could use scientific notation perhaps... `sprintf("%e",$sum);`

Comment: Please see the last part E-7 http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6273/what-does-e-mean-in-9-0122222900391e-5

Comment: I think you should add [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33687085/php-rounding-gives-00-as-an-answer#comment55146462_33687128) within your answer

Comment: Covered each and every aspects of a question +1

Comment: Thanks for explaining, looks like i'm going to have to try a different approach as JavaScript does not like these really small numbers !